# Understand Mootools Asset

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a question on Mootools Asset. My goal is loading javascript dinamically, and after loading I want to use new functions described in loaded script and set some global variable in that script which called loading.

This is my test html, but I don't understand why it doesn't work.. A is undefined...I test that in IE only so far.

thanks

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <script src='mootoolscore.js'></script>
 <script src='mootoolsmore.js'></script>
 <script>
  var a;
  var f = 'test.js';
  function seta()
    {
       a= 5;
    }
  function loadjs()
    {
     Asset.javascript(f, {id: 'myscr',
            onload:function() {
              seta();
              a = 8;
            }
     });
     alert(a);
    }
 </script>
 <div style='cursor:pointer' onclick='loadjs()'>clickme</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `onload` function will be triggered asynchronously when the asset is ready. So when you want to display the `a` variable on the `alert(a)` line, the value is not set yet.

You need to move `alert(a)` inside the `onload` function to get the result you want.

Comment: Does it mean, I can't modify global variables in Asset.onload function?

Comment: you can but your code is asynchronous. the alert will fire before the onload.